# Find values of $n$ that yield a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1$ is a prime number. Find all possible values of n.

What I have so far is this: $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1=2, n=2$$
Also, $n^2+n-2\over2$ can be factorized to be $(n+2)(n-1)\over2$.

What other values of $n$ are there, and how do you compute them? This question was from my Math Challenge II Number Theory packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $p={(n+2)(n-1)\over2}$, then $2p=(n+2)(n-1)$ and so there are only two possibilities:

- $n-1=2$ and $n+2=p$.
- $n-1=1$ and $n+2=2p$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Have you tried putting this over a common denominator and factorising the numerator?

If you are flagging this as "contest math" and aspiring to compete you really need to work through the basics before getting more of a clue than that.

Comment: edited the tag.

Comment: @JasonChen But have you tried solving the problem using this method which is essentially also what qwr suggests? Why not show an attempt to use this approach by editing the question and we can help if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} - 1 = p$

$n^2 + n -2 = 2p$, can you take it from here?